# AirDrop Not Working When Signed Into iCloud

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, keychain, airdrop

I seem to only be able to AirDrop to/from one of my Apple devices to another if one of them is signed out of iCloud. I have all my devices (iPhone X, 2017 iMac High Sierra, 2017 MacBook Air High Sierra) all signed in to my iCloud account (the same account). The devices cannot see each other in AirDrop unless I sign one of them out of iCloud.

For example, if I sign my MacBook Air out of iCloud, then my MacBook Air shows in my iMac's AirDrop and I can freely transfer files to it. Once I sign back into iCloud, it goes away.

Note: I can see and AirDrop to any of my colleagues' devices just fine across all of my devices. I just can't send to any of my own devices unless I sign out of iCloud.

I've tried all of the standard AirDrop troubleshooting (Making sure Bluetooth is on, same Wifi, update all devices, restart, etc).

Comment: Try rebooting the devices and disable do not disturb on ALL devices, it may solve your problem

Comment: Tried that already. No dice :(

Comment: Also disabling do not disturb?

Comment: Yes do not disturb is disabled on all my devices

Comment: Not sure if this falls under the standard troubleshooting, but are you hotspotting or internet sharing on these devices?

Comment: I have hotspot turned off and confirmed all devices are on the same wifi network. Bluetooth is enabled on all devices as well. Note I can send/receive via airdrop just fine to any devices that are NOT signed into my icloud account. But I can only send to one of my own devices if I sign out of iCloud first.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are all the devices named differently? What I mean is the network name, eg. "Computer Name" found under Sharing in macOS System Preferences.

Comment: They are all named differently.

Comment: I have this very weird issue when I am signed into iCloud. The AirDrop on macOS Finder keeps resetting to "No One"

Comment: I'm having this issue right now. Has a solution been found?

Comment: No but please post here if you do find a solution as I've never been able to get this resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution that worked for me. This seems unrelated but it definitely was my issue. **It also fixed my issue with Apple Watch not being able to unlock my Mac.** Below is what worked for me.

On your Mac:

1. Open up **Messages** App
2. Go to **Messages > Preferences**
3. Select **Accounts** Tab
4. Select **Blocked** Tab
5. Locate and delete any instances of your own phone number and/or email addresses
6. Close and wait ~5 minutes for iCloud to sync the changes across all your devices

On IOS:

1. Go to Settings -> Messages -> Blocked
2. Same as step 5 and 6 above

After performing those steps Airdrop worked perfectly across all devices and, as a bonus, I was able to unlock my Mac with my Apple Watch again (I was previously getting "your mac was unable to communicate with your apple watch" error / "IDS device not cloud paired").

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Because of spam callers spoofing my number, I blocked my own number last week. Airdrop stopped working around that time as well. I didn't add those two events together. This solution worked perfectly. Still curious though, why blocking my phone number blocks airdrop messages!

Answer (score 0):

Is airdrop set to everyone, or to contacts only?  If it’s set to contacts, do both devices have Contacts checked in the icloud account preferences?  Is your own card defined in your icloud contacts?

In addition, there is a very thorough list of obscure Airdrop troubleshooting tips at:  http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/20/airdrop-troubleshooting-tips-2/

Might be worth a look. Hope you find your answer!

Comment: I had tried everything in this article before posting here :/